# How to handle websockets data in an application. Where to buffer?

Tags: websocket, streaming

I am using a library called `cryptofeed` to get access to streaming real-time exchange data on cryptoexchanges. There is a lot of data once I open the websockets connection. I want to store this data on S3 as a data lake, but I worry that creating a file out of the streaming data and sending it to s3 will be too slow -- i.e., creeating the file and sending the file to S3 will be slower than the incoming streaming data eventually causing my application to run out of memory. Is this a problem? If so, what can I do? Should I use something like Kafka or Kinesis as a buffer for this streaming data? If so, how do I know that sending the data to Kafka or Kinesis will be fast enough to balance out the incoming streaming data?

This is the library: https://github.com/bmoscon/cryptofeed

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the library in question. I would recommend buffering the data in something like Redis. You can also use Kafka. Check out the backends module in the library, there are provided interfaces that will store the data for you in Kafka, Redis (and other destinations). You could also buffer to a file and periodically write it, check out the AsyncFile implementation (also in the library).